# Why CSS Grid row is not working? This is my problem

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

**Grid Row is not working**

hi, I am starting coding now, and doing a demo version of the google search page, where  I am facing a problem with (google)text. I want to move it above input, so I used grid CSS. Where I am facing a problem with grid-row. it's not working, here my code

```css
.voogle {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
}

.voogle p {
  grid-column: 5/9;
  grid-row: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="voogle">
  <p>
    <span class="V">V</span><span class="O">O</span><span class="O">O</span
        ><span class="G">G</span><span class="L">L</span
        ><span class="E">E</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

please clear my doubt? why grid row is not working.....

Comment: Because you haven't defined any grid rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Flexbox instead of grid, it's much easier in this case

```css
.voogle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center
  align-items: center
}
.voogle p {
 text-align: center
}
.V {color: #4285F4}
.O1 {color: #EA4335}
.O2 {color: #FBBC05}
.G {color: #4285F4}
.L {color: #34A853}
.E {color: #FBBC05}
```

```html
<div class="voogle">
  <p>
    <span class="V">V</span>
    <span class="O1">O</span>
    <span class="O2">O</span>
    <span class="G">G</span>
    <span class="L">L</span>
    <span class="E">E</span>
  </p>
  <input placeholder="search here">
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome, feel free to accept the answer if you found it helpful